# Error: "no current device to record from" for base R plot test in devtools::test()

Tags: r, plot, devtools, r-package, testthat

I have written a simple test in an R package to check classes of plots. It looks something like this:

```r
test_that("test works", {
  base_r_plot <- recordPlot(plot(1))
  expect_equal(class(base_r_plot), "recordedplot")
})
```

If I try and run this via `devtools::test()` I get:

```r
Error in `recordPlot(plot(1))`: no current device to record from
```

Why is that and how can I remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an interactive session, graphics devices tend to open "on their own". Running tests is, however, apparently not the same thing and a device e.g. `pdf()` needs to be opened manually. Setting it to `pdf(NULL)` will also prevent writing a superfluous `Rplots.pdf`.

```r
test_that("test works", {
  pdf(NULL) # prevent writing Rplots.pdf
  base_r_plot <- recordPlot(plot(1))
  dev.off()
  expect_equal(class(base_r_plot), "recordedplot")
})
```